# Appium With C# - How to select file from gallery with ADB command or with some other way?

Tags: c#, android, automation, appium, appium-android

I am currently automating our App (Using C# and Appium). We have the feature of uploading images from a gallery.
With Appium and through our app, I am able to open the gallery view. Need to select the image with a specific name/path.
How can this be achieved with the ADB command  (from C# code) or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it with workaround. Posting this as somebody may get some help from this.

Whatever file I want to select from device. I am pushing that file to device in camera folder with below code

```
 string destinationPathOnDevice = "/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/myfile.png";


driver.PushFile(destinationPathOnDevice, fileName, extension), new FileInfo(sourceFilePath));

//sourceFilePath = path of the file which I want to push.
```

Whenever my code opens gallery --> select "Pictures" folder.
Recently pushed file is at the top. Get all the elements (pictures) and click first element.
Note - While saving/pushing file, make sure that filename is unique.